# authorization.NET CIM expire date not validating

Tags: codeigniter, payment-gateway, authorize.net

I am using authorization CIM in sandbox. I have used following code http://developer.authorize.net/api/reference/index.html#customer-profiles-create-customer-profile (Plz see "Sample Code" tab)

Its creating Customer profile even I send an expired date. No error showing. My sandbox in "liveMode".

I have tried to add customer profile with expired date via above link (using try it feature). Then it works perfectly and show error. But whats wrong with their API??

Comment: When you submit the create profile request, are you setting validationMode to LiveMode?  If you do not, it will store the without any checks.

Comment: yes it is in setting from account. but not set by code using `validationMode()`

Answer (score 0):

The expired date is not that big of an issue when you are creating the Customer profile because that is not the profile that stores the credit card information.

A transaction in CIM is three steps. 1) Create (or retrieve) the Customer profile. 2) Create (or retrieve) the Payment profile. 3) Do the actual transaction. A valid Customer can have multiple Payment profiles (credit cards).

So then it follows - a valid Customer can have a Payment profile where they did a complete transaction - but the card has since expired. And in that case the Payment profile is still active because it can be updated with the new expiration. in other words if the card has expired you don't have to create a new payment profile for it.